# Getting segmentation fault in c, but why?

Tags: c

I wrote a function to crossover to dna segment , if one of them is `null`  it should return `-1` if they are equal  to each other it must return `-2`  , otherwise it must make crossover but I take segmentation fault ,what is the problem with my code ? 
a not : ı know what segmentation fault is.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int crossover(char** dna1, char** dna2, int crossoverIndex)

{
   char *temp;
   int a=0;

   if(dna1==NULL || dna2==NULL)
   {
       return -1;
   }
   if(dna1==dna2)
   {
       return -2;
   }

for(a=0;dna1+crossoverIndex+a;a++)
{
 temp=*(dna1+a+crossoverIndex);
*(dna1+a+crossoverIndex)=*(dna2+a+crossoverIndex);
*(dna2+a+crossoverIndex)=temp;
}
return 0;}
   int main(){
     int i,j;
     char dna1[1][3];
     char dna2[1][3];
     dna1[0][0]='G';
     dna1[0][1]='T';
     dna1[0][2]='T';
     dna1[1][0]='A';
     dna1[1][1]='G';
     dna1[1][2]='T';
     dna2[1][0]='G';
     dna2[1][1]='T';
     dna2[1][2]='T';
     dna2[0][0]='A';
     dna2[0][1]='G';
     dna2[0][2]='T';
     crossover(dna1,dna2,0);
     for(i=0;i<2;i++)
 {
   for(j=0;j<2;j++){
   printf("%c ",dna2[i][j]);
 }
printf("\n");

   }
return 0; }
```

Comment: `dna1[1][0]='A';` You know you cannot do this, because of `char dna1[1][3];`

Comment: `char dna1[1][3];` -- How many rows of characters? How many characters in each row? In C all arrays are *zero indexed* -- which row is referenced here `dna1[1][0]='A';`?

Comment: `for(a=0;dna1+crossoverIndex+a;a++)` looks like the condition to loop is always true, this is going to mess up eventually.

Comment: @Havenard How can i fix that ?

Comment: for ease of readablity and understanding: 1) don't use: `a not : ı` as most of us do not know what your trying to say.  2) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  2) consistently indent the code.  Indent after EVERY openng brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces. treat the '}' as a separate statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your arrays are only 1x3, so the only valid value for the first index is `0`, try

```
 char dna1[2][3];
 char dna2[2][3];
```

This loop's continuation check also looks suspect :

```
for (a = 0; dna1 + crossoverIndex + a; a++)
```

Comment: Actually what i am interested in is that loop, how can i fix that ?

Comment: can you explain exactly what you want the loop to do?

Comment: Thanks for your insterest and sorry for my late answer. My cell's all power was consumed . And while I was walking to my department to use computers of department , I met a friend a discussed .In case of you are interested in the problem,  the problem was  crossover for example if dna1={{'A','T','G',},{'G,G,G'},{'T','C','A'}}  and dna2={{'C','C','C'},{'T','A','C'},{'A','T','G'}} and crossoverIndex is  1 then we should change all rows with the rows of  other dna starting from 1.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all answers and comments :)
My code god two problem first of all ; 
I should write

```
char dna1[2][3];
char dna2[2][3];
```

instead of

```
char dna1[1][3];
char dna2[1][3];
```

but actually this was not my real problem because it is easy one to see ; 
the other is in the crossover function.
I should have written

```
for(a=0;*(dna1+crossoverIndex+a);a++)
```

instead of

```
 for(a=0;dna1+crossoverIndex+a;a++)
```

to stop the loop.

A not : in my problem it is guaranteed that the two dna string would have the same size .